# Flutter Accessibility text field with obscureText:true reading as "Dot" or "Full Stop"

Tags: flutter, accessibility

Flutter accessibility encounters issues when trying to enter numbers or text into a text field with `obscureText` set to true. In some devices, it reads as a full stop or dot. Is there any solution to ensure it reads correctly?

This behavior is problematic for visually impaired people.

```
TextField(
        controller: _passwordController,
        obscureText: true, // Set to true to obscure the text
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Password',
          hintText: 'Enter your password',
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I thought this package could help (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_text_input), but for some reasons having text content type set to `password` doesn't obscure the text

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of obscureText? If a visually impaired user were typing in a password and the screen reader is running, they wouldn't want their password announced to everyone. The same thing happens in plain HTML with <input type="password">. The screen reader just says "star star star" or "dot dot dot" as you type. That's a security feature.